# SQL query on Musician table

Tags: sql

The tables used are :

[image: DB schema]

To write a SQL query for bands whose members are all from different countries.

```
SELECT 
    bandmusicians.BandID, Musicians.MusicianID, Musicians.MusicianCountry    
FROM 
    bandmusicians
LEFT JOIN 
    Musicians ON bandmusicians.MusicianID = Musicians.MusicianID
ORDER BY 
    BandID
```

It returns BandID, MusicianID and MusicianCountry. How to find band which has musicians from different countries?

The DB schema and populated [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urmou.png)

Comment: This post shows no research or effort on your part.

Comment: @DBlearner please specify the database, so that other users may find this useful.

Comment: @srp ok will do that. But why does that code of yours return bands which has musicians from same countries?

Comment: The new modified query should work. I can help you more only if you provide schema and sample data.

Comment: @srp  i have attached the db schema

Answer (score 0):

try this. I have modified it.

```
select  * from band where BandID in 
(SELECT 
bm.BandID , count (distinct MusicianCountry) FROM 
bandmusicians bm
LEFT JOIN 
Musicians m ON bm.MusicianID = m.MusicianID
Group by  bm.BandID
having count (distinct MusicianCountry) > 1 )
```

Comment: It gives a  band which has two musicians from same country.

Comment: changed the having clause to  having NOT(count(*) > 1).  I got the bands which had musicians from different countries.

Comment: the above syntax may need be modified  based on the dbms.

Comment: MySQL said:  
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'distinct (MusicianCountry)) FROM 
bandmusicians bm

Comment: i think distinct is not a function in MySQL

Comment: i have modified the query . try now

Comment: select  * from bands where BandID in 
(SELECT 
bm.BandID , count(distinct m.MusicianCountry) FROM 
bandmusicians bm
LEFT JOIN 
Musicians m ON bm.MusicianID = m.MusicianID
Group by  bm.BandID
having count(distinct m.MusicianCountry) > 1 ) LIMIT 0, 25

MySQL said:  
#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)